# Preparing for a binary distribution. Hard float, soft float or both?

Tags: operating-systems, raspbian, hard-float

I have some source code that I would like to distribute as a binary to users so they don't have to wait for about 20 mins for it to compile. However, I am a bit confused about hard and soft float binaries.

1. How can I know whether a binary is soft or hard float?
2. Is there some sort of compiler flag I could use to compile soft/hard float binaries (eg sf on hf system and vice versa).
3. Will my soft float binary run on a hf system (i.e. Raspbian)?
4. Is there some way that I could make a binary that runs hf on a hard float system, and sf on soft float?

Comment: Does your code even use floating point arithmetic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1.)** I *think* you can do that with `readelf -A <binary>` and look at `Tag_ABI_HardFP_use` (I'm no expert here)

**2.)** As stated on the [Raspbian FAQ](http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianFAQ#What_compilation_options_should_be_set_Raspbian_code.3F) page. Their recommended compiler options are `-march=armv6 -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard` where  `-mfloat-abi=hard` is for hard float compilation.

**3.)** To be on the safe site you have to compile for the OS you use. That means for example Raspbian=hard float and Debian arm=soft float.

**4.)** I doubt that, but I'm no expert on it.

Or you have to write in a programming language, which doesn't need to know of that difference, because it is decided at runtime like Java.